# Convert MySQL Instr command to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(g1.moves, LENGTH('%s') + %d, INSTR(SUBSTR(g1.moves, LENGTH('%s') + %d, LENGTH(g1.moves)), ',') - 1)
, COUNT(*) 
FROM game g1 
WHERE 
   g1.moves LIKE '%s%%' 
   AND (outcome = '%s') 
GROUP BY substr(g1.moves, LENGTH('%s') + %d, INSTR(substr(g1.moves, LENGTH('%s') + %d, LENGTH(g1.moves)), ',') - 1) 
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

I have this MySQL command. My database is in PostgreSQL, so I need to convert it, however I cannot find a good way to replace the Instr function.

The structure of SQL table is as follows:

For example, let us say I have this chess game:
'e4, e5, Nf3, Nc6'

My query would essentially say, SELECT //The Next Move// where the first moves are 'e4, e5, Nf3'

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Spend some time here [String functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html).

Comment: Please explain what that is doing. Especially what is `'%s'` and `%d`?

Comment: My apologies for the vague description. I edited the post to explain my objective. The SQL command I have does this for MySQL, but I want it to convert to PostgreSQL, where the Instr() function doesn't exist.

Comment: It Postgres it is most probably a lot more efficient to store those moves in an array instead of a varchar column.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the string into an array, then you can easily extract the first three moves from that:

```
select (regexp_split_to_array(moves, ',\s*'))[:3] as first_moves, count(*)
from chess
group by first_moves;
```

The `[:3]` part selects the first three elements of the array - you can adjust that to the number of moves you want to look at.

I am not sure what `g1.moves LIKE '%s%%'` is supposed to do. If you only want to select games starting with specific moves, you can use:

```
where (regexp_split_to_array(moves, ',\s*'))[:3] = array['e4','e5','Nf3']
```

You can ditch the whole `regexp_split_to_array()` overhead if you declare the `moves` column as an array `text[]`.

---

If you want to pass the comparison values as a parameter through JDBC you can pass a string `"{e4,e5,Nf3}"` and use

```
where (regexp_split_to_array(moves, ',\s*'))[:3] = cast(? as text[])
```

Comment: This was an amazing answer! One follow-up question. How can I create the array['e4','e5','Nf3'] query if I don't actually know how many moves are gonna be in this array? I am using Java to send the queries, so it will look something like this

select (regexp_split_to_array(moves, ',\s*'))[?] as first_moves, count(*)
    from game
    where (regexp_split_to_array(moves, ',\s*'))[:?] = array['e4','e5','Nf3']
    group by first_moves;

Where the first ? is a placeholder for 4 and the second ? is a placeholder for 3. But would I go about creating placeholders for the array?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the function `position(substring in string)` for this.
INSTR in MySql is case-insensitive however but Postgresql's position is not.  Best way around this is to convert all strings to either upper or lower case like this:

`position(lower(substring) in lower(string))`.